# Is this a right statement for Closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Quote from Stoyan Stefanov's Object-Oriented JavaScript (page 84):

[image]

> If you're at point a, you're inside the global space. If you're at point b, which is 
>   inside the space of the function  F, then you have access to the global space and to 
>   the  F-space. **If you're at point  c, which is inside the function  N, then you can access 
>   the global space, the F-space and the  N-space** You cannot reach from  a to  b, because 
>   b is invisible outside  F. But you can get from c to  b if you want, or from  N to  b. The 
>   interesting thing—the closure—happens when somehow  N breaks out of  F and ends 
>   up in the global space."

I think the bold sentence above should be changed to "If you're at point c, which is inside the function N, then you can access the global space and the N-space " (the F-space shouldn't be contained, because the point c only has access to N-space and the global scope G. ).

Am I right? thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you N access to F?  N is inside F.  I think the drawing is supposed to convey that N was _declared inside_ AND _returned from_ function F.

Comment: Not necessarily "returned from" @jahroy. Other mechanisms exist for creating an external reference to an inner function, for example its direct assignment to an outer member or its attachment, as an event handler, to a DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, no.

Just about the whole point about a closure is that an external reference to an inner function keeps not only that inner function alive but also allows it to access the outer environment in which it was created, even if that outer environment arose from an executed function that has completed and returned.

I think the diagram would better illustrate closure if the blue `N` were shown inside `F` and the dotted version (the reference to `N`) were shown outside `F`.

The last sentence of the quoted statement could also be improved :

> The interesting thing — a closure - happens when an external reference to N exists, outside F.

Note that this version avoids mention of the global space. Any external scope will suffice for a closure to be formed.

The statement could go further to say that the mechanism which allows closures to be formed is the suppression of Garbage Collection.

Warning: There are many bad definitions and descriptions of "closure", both on the web and in books. Stack Overflows's current tag wiki entry for "closures" is a case in point.

Comment: Sure, there are tooo many bad descriptions of "closure", but your description("a closure ... which it was created") is the best one I ever read. Also, I feel closure should be grasped from "scope chain"'s perspective, rather than implementation comparison with other languages(e.g.,C-style stack variables).  Do you agree?

Comment: @MattElson, thanks for your kind comment. My strongest feeling on this subject is that any definition starting with "A closure is a function ..." is doomed because such definitions are not true to Landin's original concept of a closure "having an environment part and a control part". No place for it here but there is another compelling reason to move away from the ubiquitous "... is a function ..." type of definition. One day I'll get everything written down in a paper and present it at a conference.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think what it's saying is that `N` is a function that has been returned from function `F`, and therefore has access (through a closure) to variable `b` which was declared inside `F`. For example ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/LMAya/1/)):

```
function F() {
    var b = 10;
    return function () {
        console.log(b);
    };      
}

var N = F(); //N is a reference to the anonymous function returned from F

N(); //logs '10' because we still have access to b (because of the closure)
```

Comment: That's exactly how I read it: the blue circle (drawn outside the red circle, but pointing back towards it) is supposed to represent a fuction that was _returned_ from F.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not right.

The dotted circle is supposed to be representing the real scope of `N`, as being inside `F`.

Answer (score 1):

No, at point c you actually have access to he F space.

An example of this:

```
function F() {

  var b = 42;

  function N() {
    alert(b);
  }

  return N;

}

// get a reference to the function N in the global scope:
var n = F();
n(); // shows 42
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not right, look the code below.

```
// the global space
var g = 'g';

function F() {
  // the F space
  var a = 'a';
  function N () {
    // the N space
    // here you could access g in the global space and a in the F space.
    var c = 'c';
    console.log(g, a);
  }
}
```